# What does -c flag do in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, macos, terminal

In my MacOS terminal, I typed `node -c` (the `-c` flag was by mistake). But it worked exactly like `node` and I can't see any difference.
I searched online but I am unable to find any reference to the `-c` flag.

Does anyone know what it does??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `-c` flag usually checks the syntax without having your node.js script executed.

When you type, `node --help` you will see the usage listed like this,

```
  -c, --check                syntax check script without executing
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: But, when I write something in the node prompt `[>_`, it gets executed. Why is it so?

Comment: Yeah. It does, It is nothing but a CUI implementation of the V8 engine. Hence whatever you can accomplish in your developer console, can be done here as well.

Comment: then, how does -c makes a difference? Can you refer me to any example?

Answer (score 1):

If you type `node --help` you can get all available options.

`-c, --check syntax check script without executing`

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation:

-c, --check

Check the script's syntax without executing it. Exits with an error code if script is invalid.